# Is there auto-typing suggestion listing from page 2 in Google sheet with only typing 1 or 2 characters?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm setting up a form that typing every single time and finding ways that could save more time.

I have a list of locations, e.g.

```
Sitka
Wrangell
Jacksonville
Nashville
Los Angeles
San Antonio
San Diego
```

I made the verification listing(suggesting answer from sheet 2) when I typing, "San" it shows "San Antonio" and "San Diego", but when I typing "an" it shows nothing.

I have a really long list, please help if that would be able to type characters that match inside words. 
eg, 
Typing "ll"
Showing "Wrangell" "Jacksonville" "Nashville"

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

put your stuff in some column (which you can hide) and then create a Data Validation for your input cell:

[image: 0]

---

and then just type and it will auto-suggest you like this:

[image: 0]